# my jupyter notebook has permission problems, it can't extract files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory, tar

i'm running a colab locally with notebook running under anaconda, it gets stuck extracting files with tar and gives me error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'content\wav2lip-HD\.git\objects\pack\pack-96550f853b066e3b45ab460b353c82954661024f.idx'"

here's a sample of the code that gets stuck

```
with tarfile.open('./content/wav2lip-cache.tar.gz', 'r:gz') as tar:
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    print("Current directory:", current_directory)
    for member in tar.getmembers():
      target_path = os.path.join('/', member.name)
      try:
        tar.extract(member, '/')
      except:
        pass
  with tarfile.open('./content/wav2lip-HD.tar.gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall('content')
```

the root folder for the notebook is in documents and i'm the sole user so i'm not expecting any permission problems
something important to note is that wget can write files to the content folder

i've tried:
changing perms of the folder
running anaconda prompt & navigator under admin perms
checking the code for errors
checking i was in the right directory
turning windows defender off

i already had all perms of the folder, running with admin perms changed nothing and the code has no errors

Comment: Why do you have a git repo in there at all?  Is it possible the file already exists from the first unpack?

Comment: the .git folder is inside of the tar archive, for some reason the error just stopped appearing and now it works, strange